# Ansible Playbook with Loopback IP specific per host

Tags: ansible

I'm trying create a playbook that will configure the same config on 200+ hosts but with one part of the config being specific to each host (ip addresses 4th octet).  Example below:

Where host r1 = 192.168.0.1, loopback IP address should be 10.0.0.1 and so on for r2, r3 etc.

Wondered about using host file variables but a bit out of my depth.

```yaml
---
- name: Add Loopback Playbook
  hosts: r1
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  
  vars:
    cli:
      username: cisco
      password: cisco
      auth_pass: cisco
          
  tasks:
  - name: Add Loopback Interface
    ios_config:
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
      authorize: yes
      auth_pass: "{{ cli }}"
      parents: interface loopback1
      lines:
      - description *** Management Interface ***
      - ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options. The loopback IP can be derived from the hostname. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
r11
r12
r13
```

The tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        loopback: "{{ inventory_hostname|
                      regex_replace(my_regex, my_replace) }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^r(.*)$'
        my_replace: '10.1.0.\1'
    - debug:
        var: loopback
```

give

```yaml
ok: [r12] => {
    "loopback": "10.1.0.12"
}
ok: [r11] => {
    "loopback": "10.1.0.11"
}
ok: [r13] => {
    "loopback": "10.1.0.13"
}
```

---

This can be simplified if there are no numbers in the prefix. For example, the task below gives the same results

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        loopback: "{{ inventory_hostname|
                      select('match', '[0-9]')|
                      list|join() }}"
```

---

A more robust solution would be to create the group dynamically in the fist play and use it in the second one. For example, the playbook below also gives the same results

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    prefix: r
    start: 11
    stop: 13
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        groups:
          - my_group
        hostname: "{{ prefix }}{{ item }}"
        loopback: "10.1.0.{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ range(start, stop|int + 1)|list }}"

- hosts: my_group
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: loopback
```

---

The next option is to create the inventory. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    prefix: r
    start: 11
    stop: 13
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: hosts
        content: |
          {% for i in range(start, stop + 1) %}
          {{ prefix }}{{ i }} loopback=10.1.0.{{ i }}
          {% endfor %}
```

creates the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
r11 loopback=10.1.0.11
r12 loopback=10.1.0.12
r13 loopback=10.1.0.13
```

Then the playbook below gives also the same results

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: loopback

shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml
```

---

In the same way, it's possible to create a dictionary in group_vars. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    prefix: r
    start: 1
    stop: 255
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: group_vars/routers/loopback.yml
        content: |
          loopback:
          {% for i in range(start, stop + 1) %}
            {{ prefix }}{{ i }}: 10.1.0.{{ i }}
          {% endfor %}
```

creates the file with the dictionary in `group_vars`

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/routers/loopback.yml
loopback:
  r1: 10.1.0.1
  r2: 10.1.0.2
  r3: 10.1.0.3
  ...
```

Then the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: loopback[inventory_hostname]
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [r2] => {
    "loopback[inventory_hostname]": "10.1.0.2"
}
ok: [r4] => {
    "loopback[inventory_hostname]": "10.1.0.4"
}
ok: [r1] => {
    "loopback[inventory_hostname]": "10.1.0.1"
}
ok: [r3] => {
    "loopback[inventory_hostname]": "10.1.0.3"
}
ok: [r5] => {
    "loopback[inventory_hostname]": "10.1.0.5"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've managed to lab up a playbook using the hostname/regex to define the loopbacks, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your host are in a group (let's call it `routers`), you can get the index of a host within the group and use that to generate an ip address.  For example, let's say we have an inventory file that looks something like:

```
all:
  children:
    routers:
      hosts:
        r1:
        r2:
        r3:
        r4:
        r5:
```

We can write a playbook like this:

```
---
- name: Add Loopback Playbook
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  vars:
    cli:
      username: cisco
      password: cisco
      auth_pass: cisco

  tasks:
    - name: Add Loopback Interface
      debug:
        msg: "ip address for {{ inventory_hostname }} is {{ address }}"
      vars:
        address: "10.0.0.{{groups.routers.index(inventory_hostname)+1}}"
```

Which will output:

```
PLAY [Add Loopback Playbook] ******************************************************************

TASK [Add Loopback Interface] *****************************************************************
ok: [r2] => {
    "msg": "ip address for r2 is 10.0.0.2"
}
ok: [r3] => {
    "msg": "ip address for r3 is 10.0.0.3"
}
ok: [r4] => {
    "msg": "ip address for r4 is 10.0.0.4"
}
ok: [r1] => {
    "msg": "ip address for r1 is 10.0.0.1"
}
ok: [r5] => {
    "msg": "ip address for r5 is 10.0.0.5"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work assuming there are no gaps in ip's being used.  I've actually got another use for this also so will come in very handy.